# Extending Immutable types (or: fast cache for immutable types) in OCaml

Tags: caching, hashtable, ocaml, immutability

I have a recursive immutable data structure in ocaml which can be simplified to something like this:

```
type expr =
{
    eexpr : expr_expr;
    some_other_complex_field : a_complex_type;
}

and expr_expr =
    | TInt of int
    | TSum of (expr * expr)
    | TMul of (expr * expr)
```

It's an AST, and sometimes it gets pretty complex (it's very deep).

there is a recursive function that evaluates an expression. For example, let's say,

```
let rec result expr =
    match expr.eexpr with
        | TInt i -> i
        | TSum (e1, e2) -> result e1 + result e2
        | TMul (e1, e2) -> result e1 * result e2
```

Now suppose I am mapping an expression to another expression, and I need to constantly check the result of an expr, sometimes more than once for the same expr, and sometimes for expressions that were recently mapped by using the pattern

```
{ someExpr with eexpr = TSum(someExpr, otherExpr) }
```

Now, the result function is very lightweight, but running it many times for a deep AST will not be very optimized. I know I could cache the value using a Hashtbl, but AFAIK the Hashtbl will only do structural equality, so it will need to traverse my long AST anyway.
I know the best option would be to include a probably immutable "result" field in the expr type. But I can't.

So is there any way in Ocaml to cache a value to an immutable type, so I don't have to calculate it eagerly every time I need it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the functorial interface to control the kind of equality used by the hash table.  I believe the semantics of (==) are legitimate for your purposes; i.e., if A == B then f A = f B for any pure function f.  So you can cache the results of f A.  Then if you find a B that's physically equal to A, the cached value is correct for B.

The downside of using (==) for hashing is that the hash function will send all structurally equal objects to the same hash bucket, where they will be treated as distinct objects.  If you have a lot of structurally equal objects in the table, you get no benefit from the hashing.  The behavior degenerates to a linear search.

You can't define the hash function to work with physical addresses, because the physical addresses can be changed at any time by the garbage collector.

However, if you know your table will only contain relatively few large-ish values, using physical equality might work for you.

Comment: Thanks, Jeffrey for the great response! So most likely I can do the same behavior with a List and a function that will lookup the list with == then ?
I read at the ocaml manual that physical equality has undefined behavior for immutable structures, although it's guaranteed that when A == B then A = B (of course). When I use the pattern { expr with eexpr = TAdd(expr, otherExpr) }, is it guaranteed that in TAdd(thisExpr, _) thisExpr == expr ?

Comment: A hash table will work better than a list, because it will sort into bins by approximate structural equality (i.e., the usual hash function).  Unless all your values are structurally equal, this will be better than using just one list.  (You can tailor your hash function to look at the parts that differ the most often.)  Like I said, I think the semantics of (==) for immutable values are OK for your purposes.  There are no strong guarantees of what is (==) to what, the runtime is allowed to be arbitrarily clever with pure values (one reason FP is so cool).  But I'd say yes, in practice.

Comment: Oh I see! But then it'd have to traverse the big AST every time it hashes to compare, wouldn't it? my "result" function is fairly lightweight, so maybe it would turn out to be slower than calling it eagerly, wouldn't it?

Comment: I'm thinking about maybe using a Hashtbl of position, and then search linearly. This would be the best to my case, but it's a pity it's something very specific of how the application I'm working on is designed

Comment: The hash function doesn't have to traverse the whole structure.  It's just an approximation.  In fact, the predefined hash function doesn't traverse the whole structure.  You can write a hash function that does whatever you like (through the functorial interface).  It just has to obey the obvious semantic (two values that compare equal by your equality function must hash to the same value).

Comment: That's great to know! But anyway since I've got a fairly unique data (position), I think I'll implement my own hashing function then! So I'll just write the equal using == and hash using the position data! Thank you !

Comment: @JeffreyScofield, just a note: I think your paragraph on "the semantics of `==`" is a bit off. if `A == B`, then of course `f A` and `f B` would return the same result *for any function f*. That does not mean that calling `f A` and `f B` in turn would return the same result (that is, just as calling `f A` twice may return different result), but I'm not sure how this distinction is relevant. I would rather say that "pure" functions are characterized by `A = B`, rather than `A == B`, being a sufficient condition -- I would consider using `==` impure.

Comment: Here's what I'm thinking.  The docs say: "On non-mutable structures, the behavior of (==) is implementation-dependent; however, it is guaranteed that e1 == e2 implies compare e1 e2 = 0."  This seems good enough to guarantee that A == B implies f A = f B for pure f and non cyclic A and B.  It's not true for *any function* f if f is impure (or you could say that f is not a function in that case of course).  Let me know where this reasoning fails, I could easily have messed up.

Comment: (Sorry, another comment: I agree that (==) is a little bit hacky or impure.  That's why I think you need to be careful to follow only what is guaranteed by the language.  You don't want to start depending on what just happens to be true in a given implementation.)

Answer (score 5):

Hash-cons the values of `expr_expr`. By doing this structurally equal values in your program will share exactly the same memory representation and you can substitute structural equality (`=`) by physical equality (`==`).

This [paper](http://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/ftp/publis/hash-consing2.pdf) should get you quickly started on hash-consing in OCaml.

Comment: Hash-cons is a great functionality! I didn't know it existed! But my AST has got some very complex values, like that "a_complex_type" I mentioned. It's got lazy values, functions, and normally there's no way to compare with structural equality that a_complex_type . Would hash-cons work in this context?

Comment: Also it's most likely impossible to find the same values in my AST (which contains position locations also), but when I use the construct { expr with eexpr =TAdd(expr, otherExpr) } so it seems to me that the has-cons is unnecessary there. But it's a great, and informative paper. Thanks!
Now, I've read that ocaml physical equality has undefined behavior on immutable structures. Is it safe to use it without has-cons, like @Jeffrey proposed? This should probably be enough!

Comment: Regarding the fact that you type is more complex than that. If all of its constituents can be constructed with hash-consed constructors, it won't be a problem. Position information is effectively problematic. Without that you could easily memoize the `result` function with a weak hashtable, also for the intermediate results of the recursive calls.

Comment: Yeah, I wish I could change the structure to use hash-cons ! But really thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can merge the two ideas above : use hash-consing-like techniques to get the hash of the "pure expression" part of your data, and use this hash as key in the memoization table for the `eval` function.

Of course this only works when your `eval` function indeed only depends on the "pure expression" part of the function, as in the example you gave. I believe that is a relatively general case, at least if you restrict yourself to storing the *successful* evaluations (that won't, for example, return an error including some location information).

*Edit:* a small proof of concept:

```
type 'a _expr =
  | Int of int
  | Add of 'a * 'a

(* a constructor to avoid needing -rectypes *)
type pure_expr = Pure of pure_expr _expr

type loc = int
type loc_expr = {
  loc : loc;
  expr : loc_expr _expr;
  pure : pure_expr (* or any hash_consing of it for efficiency *)
}

(* this is where you could hash-cons *)
let pure x = Pure x

let int loc n =
  { loc; expr = Int n; pure = pure (Int n) }
let add loc a b =
  { loc; expr = Add (a, b); pure = pure (Add(a.pure, b.pure)) }

let eval =
  let cache = Hashtbl.create 251 in
  let rec eval term =
    (* for debug and checking memoization *)
    Printf.printf "log: %d\n" term.loc;
    try Hashtbl.find cache term.pure with Not_found ->
      let result =
        match term.expr with
          | Int n -> n
          | Add(a, b) -> eval a + eval b in
      Hashtbl.add cache term.pure result;
      result
  in eval



let test = add 3 (int 1 1) (int 2 2)
# eval test;;
log: 3
log: 2
log: 1
- : int = 3
# eval test;;
log: 3
- : int = 3
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but unfortunately the way my data is stored I don't think I can separate the pure expression from the mostly unique data, since they are mutually recursive structures

Comment: @Waneck: I added a small implementation that does the separation, to show what I was thinking of.